# Pygame change cursor to OS cursor

Tags: python, pygame, operating-system, mouse-cursor

Is there a simple way to use pygame to switch to an OS-defined cursor? For example, switching to the windows loading circle or apple beach-ball when loading, or changing to arrows when hovering over a draggable object?

Pygame provides the [cursor](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/cursors.html) module for loading a bitmap to replace the cursor, but I'd like to defer to the OS-defined cursors instead.

Comment: find OS cursors on disk, convert to bitmap and use with PyGame.

Comment: Pygame's cursors are only in monochrome, and many OS pointers are in color. Also, reading a file from the OS like that would require elevated permissions on most systems, and it would require a completely different approach for every OS. Not really a good solution.

Comment: You can "create" your own cursor by just making the default one not visible and using mouse motion events to draw your own image to the cursors location. But this is also not that great as you'd need to check the operating system to choose what set of cursors to draw, and you'd have to store all of these images with your program. But it's certainly possible.

Comment: I'm trying to not "create" cursors. I just want the program to use the native OS cursors, like basically any other program can do. Things like changing the pointer to the text input whenever you're mousing over something you can type in.

Answer (score 1):

From: [link](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html), if anyone still finds it useful:
you can use the `pygame.mouse.set_cursor` method with e. g. `pygame.SYSTEM_CURSOR_WAIT` as the first argument.