# Stop pygame from changing cursor

Tags: python, pygame, mouse-cursor

How do I prevent the cursor from changing when over a pygame window (or, equivalently, set the cursor to the OS default)?

Related:
[Pygame change cursor to OS cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839550/pygame-change-cursor-to-os-cursor)

Answer (score 1):

I won't be certain about this but it might be that your code is trying to change your cursor.

At the very end of the main loop, put the following code.

```
pygame.mouse.set_system_cursor(pygame.SYSTEM_CURSOR_ARROW)
```

Might be completely wrong though.

Comment: Note: Pygame 2.0.0 and up only

Answer (score 0):

You need get your os cursor and convert it to a bitmap.
Now set the cursor with
`pygame.mouse.set_cursor(YOUR_CURSOR)`.

Source: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/cursors.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows 10, you can mimic the cursor with:

```
 cursor_text = (
 'X                       ',
 'XX                      ',
 'X.X                     ',
 'X..X                    ',
 'X...X                   ',
 'X....X                  ',
 'X.....X                 ',
 'X......X                ',
 'X.......X               ',
 'X........X              ',
 'X.........X             ',
 'X..........X            ',
 'X......XXXXX            ',
 'X...X..X                ',
 'X..X X..X               ',
 'X.X  X..X               ',
 'XX    X..X              ',
 '      X..X              ',
 '       XX               ',
 '                        ',
 '                        ',
 '                        ',
 '                        ',
 '                        ')
 cs, mask = pygame.cursors.compile(cursor_text)
 cursor = ((24, 24), (0, 0), cs, mask)
 pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*cursor)
```